# BASH: Basic if then and variable assignment set a Cron Job

Tags: bash

I'm a newbie in Bash, I tried without success an if statement where I have two variable numbers `a` and `b`.

I want to output `$check` only if `$b` is greater than `1` so I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(shuf -i 1-59 -n 1);

b=$(shuf -i 1-10 -n 1);

if [ $b -gt 1 ];
then
  check="*/$a * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/requests/check.php > /dev/null"
fi

{
  echo $check
} | crontab -u ubuntu -
```

It doesn't work, why I get this error message? `"-":0: bad day-of-month`

Comment: Did you look at what happens when you `echo $check` *without* piping it to `crontab`? Compare with `echo "$check"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's couple problems with your script.

#### 1. Unquoted $check variable

In this part,

```
{
  echo $check
} | crontab -u ubuntu -
```

`echo $check` will expand to `echo */$2 * * * * <other text here>` , but bash `*` will  perform filename expansion to the contents of the current working directory of the script on each of the glob star symbols. Thus, effectively, your `crontab` receives completely incorrect final string.

#### 2. Potential null variable

Your `$check` variable set if and only if `$b` is greater than 1. Well, what happens when `$b` is 1 ?  your variable won't be set.

```
if [ $b -gt 1 ];
then
     check="*/$a * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/requests/check.php > /dev/null"
fi
```

That also means when you `echo` the variable, your `crontab` command will receive a null string. Thus, you might want to implement another if statement there to check whether `$check` variable is null, like

```
if [ "x$check" != "x"  ];
then
    echo "$check" | crontab -u ubuntu -
fi
```

And of course, please please please, for the love of shell scripting , quote your string variables.

---

As requested in the comments, multiple entries could be output to crontab in a similar fashion:

```
$ check1="*/2 * * * * bash -c 'wall <<< \"check1\"'"                                                               

$ check2="*/2 * * * * bash -c 'wall <<< \"check1\"'"                                                               

$ printf "%s\n" "$check1" "$check2" | crontab -u $USER -
```

The idea here is that `printf` keeps processing arguments until all are exhausted so it's basically same as a for loop. Alternatively, one could append each desired crontab string into array, and iterate using for loop via that same array.

Comment: I'd assumed the OP was going for a string of the form `*/2 * * * *` in which case the *format* is OK I think (every two minutes) - it's the fact that `$check` is unquoted in the echo to `crontab` that's the issue (`*` gets expanded to a list of files...?)

Comment: @steeldriver exactly what I was writing, indeed the shuffle number is between 1 and 59

Comment: @steeldriver  didn't know `*/2` syntax is acceptable.   I'll add that to my answer then. And yes, likely the quoting is a major issue

Comment: Thank you very much, really useful also your final tip about quotes

Comment: @NineCattoRules see [@malo's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/881322/178692) for more details / examples

Comment: @steeldriver yes, but I choose this one because there's also the 2nd point regards to null variable

Comment: is it too much to ask you an example with multiple cron jobs? I need to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/878647/4458531) right?

Comment: @NineCattoRules oh, not at all, I can give an example of that. I just need to know if you have a specific command that you want , or specific timing

Comment: Let's say I wanna output the first `$check` together with this one `check2="*/$c * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/requests/check2.php > /dev/null"`and for it I need another same if statement...I tried but it outputs only the last echo

Comment: @NineCattoRules I added a small example. I might edit it a little later with a better one. For now I have to leave. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @NineCattoRules that's just command. You could substitute your `/usr/bin/php...` there.

Comment: @NineCattoRules i will it a bit later. I'm short on time right  now

Comment: wonderful with `printf`...if null is set it doesn't matter because on Crontab it's ok

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you full understand command substitution in BASH.
I removed the pipe to crontab for testing and understanding. 
you can put it in place again with:

```
echo "$check"|crontab -u ubuntu -
```

but please have a look to this example here first:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

a=$(shuf -i 1-59 -n 1)
b=$(shuf -i 1-10 -n 1)

if [ $b -gt 1 ]
then
  check='*/'${a}' * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/requests/check.php > /dev/null'
fi

echo "$check"
```

You need to read manuals to understand how BASH works as an interpreter. There is too much to explain here.
One more hint: you can do syntax check with

```
bash -n script-name
```

Teach yourself with the following examples and try to understand them and you will understand your problem above :-)

```
echo *
echo "*"
echo '*'
X='*';echo $X
X='*';echo "$X"
X="*";echo "$X"
```

That's important to understand how and why to quote.